# Graphview line chart is not showing all the data points

Tags: java, android, mpandroidchart, android-graphview

I am creating a plot for my android app using graphview library, but the line chart is not showing all the data points.

I have already tried with different data sets, manually changing X-Y bound, but unable to fix.

this is the data set (x, y):

```
0.027616246868734515, 0.007854651482080012
0.02384627564469148, 0.00789924349849511
0.02117807669545499, 0.007941408464975257
0.020058627833574472, 0.007981469914748886
0.020072430035288694, 0.007994247157591203
0.02075702555156617, 0.008025737425449271
0.023093950612551192, 0.008067902299127112
0.026639815506611847, 0.008107586011190594
```

this is the graphview customization:

```
GridLabelRenderer gridLabel = chart.getGridLabelRenderer();
gridLabel.setHorizontalAxisTitle(xtitle);
gridLabel.setVerticalAxisTitle(ytitle);
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance();
nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(5);
chart.getGridLabelRenderer().setLabelFormatter(new DefaultLabelFormatter(nf, nf));
chart.getViewport().scrollToEnd();
chart.getViewport().setXAxisBoundsManual(true);
chart.getViewport().setMinX(0);
chart.getViewport().setMaxX(0.040000);
chart.getGridLabelRenderer().setHumanRounding(false);
chart.getGridLabelRenderer().setNumHorizontalLabels(6);
```

This is showing data points 0,1,2,3,4,7 and missing 5,6.
I have already tried with default X and Y bound, but that is showing just one datapoint.

Comment: Check this if it works for you https://github.com/rohitksingh/Bulucu/blob/59257b9152d92c19d8481609691471522009f557/Bulucu/app/src/main/java/com/freewifi/rohksin/freewifi/Activities/TrackWifiActivity.java#L113

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if anyone wants to know:

It draws vertical lines as expected in 4.1.0 but not 4.2.0 or 4.2.1.